# Need help. 7777

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I am new to Ethereum. I have products I'd like to sell using smart contracts but I am to old and to tired in the brain to learn how to write a smart contract myself. Is there a process in place for me to talk with and select a programmer or a set of programmers to write contracts I can use to sell my digital as well as physical products?

Comment: Try to ask that question over at the [ethereum gitter channels](https://gitter.im/orgs/ethereum/rooms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [jobs.ethercasts.com](http://jobs.ethercasts.com)
Or use a freelancer portal like [upwork.com](http://upwork.com)
Or you can contact me via a temporary email to discuss your project: zkxkxniv@tafmail.com